# Can not simulate stability of op-amp without negative supply rail

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, stability

I am simply trying to simulate stability of AD8531 op-amp in a buffer configuration.
[image]

However, when I connect the VSS pin to GND, I have some meaningless result.
[image]
If the op-amp is fed with at least -1V, the results seems reasonable to me.
[image]
Since it is AC analysis, I think the issue should not be clipping but if you have any ideas, please share with me.
Thanks.

Comment: Vin+ is connected to ground hence why would you expect a sensible result? Explain why you think it should work.

Comment: I just connected input DC source to GND to run AC analysis. In such a configuration, loop gain is equal to output voltage so I can see the result directly. By the way, I put a DC source to Vin+, it still does not work properly.

Comment: The model uses a very generic configuration, with some MOSFETs at input and output, only. Don't expect miracles.

Answer (score 1):

Spice always does a dc simulation, before running an ac simulation.  It finds the dc voltages at all the nodes, then uses its knowledge of devices to make a linear model for the ac analysis. If the model for the op amp is one that does not allow a input common mode range that includes ground, the op amp will not work as you expect for ac analysis, with no negative power supply. This is probably what is happening.

Comment: Yes, it might be the reason. Because I do not get unreasonable results for other op-amp models such as AD8538.